How to remove a runtime variable?
I have some variable in the Runtime Variables section of a collection that I don't want anymore. Is there a way to remove it? I initally created it via the Vars tab in the Post Request section.
I can't edit it when I select configure at the bottom of the environments dropdown in the top right because that only shows environment variables, not runtime variables. When I click on the eye icon, I see the variable and it's value but no way to modify.

Actually, I just came across this issue as well.
As of now, there is no dedicated UI for this. You have to delete runtime vars the same way you create them, through pre- or post-request scripts.
So if we have a token var set based on API response, we should have in the script section of the api request:
//Save the response var 'token' as a runtime var 
bru.setVar("token",res.body.token); 

Once the runtime var is defined, closing bruno or re-importing the collection should remove it. But if you need to remove it frequently, you can use:
//Delete the 'token' runtime var 
bru.deleteVar("token");

